# Group words in string with count using function

Tags: php, function, count, grouping

I need some help in getting the count of the array in string.

I have an array with 5 words :

```
$array_planet = array('[Sun]', '[Moon]', '[Mercury]', '[Venus]', '[Mars]');
```

and I've many strings that look like :

```
$string_source = 'blabla[Sun][Sun]blabla[Moon][Moon][Moon]blabla[Sun][Sun][Sun][Sun]blabla[Venus]';
```

I need a function to return :

```
$string_out = 'blabla[Sun][2]blabla[Moon][3]blabla[Sun][4]blabla[Venus][1]';
```

`blabla` can be any length and values.

Comment: Have you tried `array_count_values` ?

Comment: array_count_values return me [Sun][6], but i need [Sun][2]blabla[Sun][4]

Comment: Consider accepting one of the give nanswers. They are all good and people took time to help you which should be appretiated. Also it prevents this question from getting any more unneeded attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$string_source = preg_replace_callback('/(\[[^\[\]]+\])+/', function($matches)
{
   return $matches[1].'['.(strlen($matches[0])/strlen($matches[1])).']';
}, $string_source);
```

note, I do not rely on planets array because regex replace don't need to do it.

Fiddle is available [here](http://3v4l.org/Ha8Yr)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)  to achieve this:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/(\[.*?])+/', function($m) {
    return $m[1].'['.substr_count($m[0], $m[1]).']';
}, $string_source);
```

Output:

```
blabla[Sun][2]blabla[Moon][3]blabla[Sun][4]blabla[Venus][1]
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/134304)

Comment: It should not be `[Sun][Sun]2` , It should be `[Sun][2]`

Comment: I don't see that reflected on the demo , still shows the same . Please check again. @AmalMurali

Comment: blabla CAN BE ANY LENGTH AND VALUES

Comment: @AmalMurali, Please double check before commenting , your demo still shows `blabla[Sun][Sun][2]` OP wants `blabla[Sun][2]blabla[`

Comment: Using `substr_count()` for this isn't a good idea. It will produce `O(n)` complexity while `strlen()` is always `O(1)`. Sample comparative tests code is [here](http://pastebin.com/RP97WCnZ) - I've used [benchmarking tool](https://github.com/almadomundo/benchmark) to measure time usage. Results are [here](http://pastebin.com/BiUXbSVa). And it's obvious - the longer the string - the worse are results with `substr_count()`

Comment: @AlmaDo: If performance is a concern, sure, your version is more preferable. It's unlikely the OP was trying to find the *most* efficient way though. This was meant as a shorter, alternative approach :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get the parts from your string, so you end up havin something like this:

```
array = (
 0= > 'blabla[Sun][Sun]',
 1 => 'blabla[Moon][Moon][Moon]',
 2 => 'blabla[Sun][Sun][Sun][Sun]',
 3 => 'blabla[Venus]'
);
```

Then iterate over the array and use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [substr_count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php).

Comment: blabla can be any length and values

Comment: i know. it would still work but you have to do *some* thinking yourself here :)